# LinkedIn App Browser Issues: Background Video and Animations

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-video, linkedin-api, browser-detection

When you open a website in LinkedIn's app (iOS), html5 background videos set to autoplay do not play, and animations do not fire unless you stop scrolling. So, it often looks like there is a bunch of empty space when you use fade and slide animations.

Here are a few examples (**you must view within LinkedIn's app to see the issue**)...

Background video

https://jobs.netflix.com/

https://thelovinggroup.com/ (also has animation issues)

Animations

https://voidwatches.com/

http://www.clearmotion.com/

Any thoughts on how to tackle this issue until LinkedIn builds a better browser?

I've looked into browser detection as a possible solution. Thinking maybe I could do an if/else statement to check if it's a common browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc.), else do something else with those videos and animations.

But everything I've read for browser detection strongly recommends against using it unless you absolutely have to (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent).

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Ok, so I've implemented the code from this Github project to detect UIWebView: https://github.com/simpleweb/UIWebView-Detect

And it works well! However, I really need to differentiate between LinkedIn and other apps with WebView because LinkedIn is the only one with these issues.

I used Udger's parser (based on what I found in another Stack Overflow post): https://udger.com/resources/online-parser

And I can see that Facebook has its own browser, but LinkedIn seems to be using some version of Safari.

I feel like I'm starting to get closer, but I'm still not sure I've come up with a solid solution.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I wanted to share a link to my product page that has autoplay videos on it and it's not playing.

Comment: Unfortunately not...I think we're stuck with it until LinkedIn improves their app :(

Comment: After 2 years looks like the problem still remains, muted videos with autoplay just stay still like an image and I couldn't find any way to play it. Maybe someone has a solution after all this time?

Comment: Unfortunately I never found a solution. After spending quite a bit of time on it, we just scrapped the project and moved on. It's kind of amazing/funny to me that LinkedIn has this issue and hasn't fixed it.